# Bash Script and quoting SED

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sed

Below is my script where it will either accept a file input or stdin... but I can't get the escaping right! - I've tried single and double quotes etc...

```
while read line
do
sed 's/path\/12345/path\/12345 == useful name/g'
sed 's/path\/6789/path\/6789 == useful name - 2/g'
done < ${1:-/dev/stdin}
```

Comment: Note that generating file names (paths) with spaces in the names is going to stress your scripting — you'll need to be careful as you manipulate the files and directories.  It can be done; you just have to be careful (double quotes are your friend).

Comment: Thanks I'm only attempting to update the text ie in myfile.txt I have a line that says `path/12345` and I want to replace that with `path/12345 == useful name

Comment: When you are using `sed` to manipulate paths, it is almost always a good idea to change the delimiter. `sed 's@path/12345@path/12345 == useful name@g'`

Comment: When you have a lot different "translations" (6789 or 12345 possibilities?), you do not want to maintain them in your script.You can generate sed comamnds from a cfg file, but an awk solution would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sed` commands read from standard input, as does the `while read` loop.  This leads to confusion.

You probably want just this (no `while read; do …; done` loop around it — see the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120997/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-tony)):

```
sed -e 's/path\/12345/path\/12345 == useful name/g' \
    -e 's/path\/6789/path\/6789 == useful name - 2/g' \
    "$@"
```

Inside a script, that will run the `sed` script on all the files specified on the command line, or standard input if no files are specified.  That's what the `"$@"` means in this context.

```
$ cat > script.sh
sed -e 's/path\/12345/path\/12345 == useful name/g' \
    -e 's/path\/6789/path\/6789 == useful name - 2/g' \
    "$@"
$ bash script.sh
path/12345
path/12345 == useful name
path/23456
path/23456
path/6789
path/6789 == useful name - 2
android-path/67890-twirling
android-path/6789 == useful name - 20-twirling
$
```

I typed 4 lines:

```
path/12345
path/23456
path/6789
android-path/67890-twirling
```

The other lines are the output from the script.  When I put the four typed lines into a file `data`, I got the output:

```
$ bash script.sh data
path/12345 == useful name
path/23456
path/6789 == useful name - 2
android-path/6789 == useful name - 20-twirling
$
```

That looks like what the script is supposed to do.  We can debate whether the last line *should* be mapped, but the expressions used in the script do the mapping that's shown.

Comment: I must be missing something - it doesn't work. The script doesn't output anything - I run the script and it waits for some stdinput - I put in path\12345 hit enter and get nothing, just another line -

Comment: `path\12345` won't match the `path/12345` pattern, will it?  Where was the typo?

Comment: Sorry yes, that was a typo (its right in the script).

Comment: Have you still got problems?  Which platform are you running on?  Which shell are you using?  Can you copy/paste my script, my data?  What results do you get with those?  Note that there can be no spaces after the trailing backslashes.

Comment: Maybe use `s#..#..#g` for avoiding typo's.

Comment: @WalterA: Yes, it would be feasible (and probably sensible) to use `#` instead of `/` to avoid needing to escape the `/` in the pattern and replacement — as long as `#` won't figure as part of the string.  However, the OP seems to have that part nailed, so it isn't an urgent change.  There's something else going on that's giving grief.

Comment: It looks like when I pass it a file it works - YET when I try to give it input via stdin I get nothing... perhaps it doesn't know to write to stdout?

Comment: `sed` always writes to `stdout` unless you make it write somewhere else (see the `w` command, for example).  Are you piping the standard output through `tee` or anything?  Or are you running it directly at the command line with no I/O redirection?  What happens when you indicate EOF to the script (Control-D on most Unix systems; Control-Z on Windows)?  What happens if you run `bash script.sh < data`?

Comment: directly at the command line - no redirection ./script.sh ENTER - then put my string path/12345 ENTER and I get nada

Comment: Curious.  Are you running on BSD, HP-UX, AIX, Solaris, Mac OS X, Linux, Windows or something else?  Are you using Bash or some other shell?  No output is puzzling; unmapped output is easily explicable, but no output is odd.  Especially if it works OK with a file.

Comment: osX - bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin15)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120997/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-tony).